# Complex multiple join query across 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

`shops`, PRIMARY KEY `cid,zbid`
`shop_items`, PRIMARY KEY `id`
`shop_inventory`, PRIMARY KEY `id`

`shops a` is related to `shop_items b` by the following: `a.cid=b.cid AND a.zbid=b.szbid`
`shops` is not directly related to `shop_inventory`

`shop_items b` is related to `shop_inventory c` by the following: `b.cid=c.cid AND b.id=c.iid`

Now, I would like to run a query which returns `a.*` (all columns from `shops`). That would be:

```
SELECT a.* FROM shops a WHERE a.cid=1 AND a.zbid!=0
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause is necessary.

Next, I want to return the number of items in each shop:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  COUNT(b.id) items
FROM shops a
LEFT JOIN shop_items b ON b.cid=a.cid AND b.szbid=a.zbid
WHERE a.cid=1
GROUP BY b.szbid,b.cid
```

As you can see, I have added a `GROUP BY` clause for this to work.

Next, I want to return the average price of each item in the shop. This isn't too hard:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  COUNT(b.id) items,
  AVG(COALESCE(b.price,0)) average_price
FROM shops a
LEFT JOIN shop_items b ON b.cid=a.cid AND b.szbid=a.zbid
WHERE a.cid=1
GROUP BY b.szbid,b.cid
```

My next criteria is where it gets complicated. I also want to return the unique buyers for each shop. This can be done by querying `shop_inventory c`, getting the `COUNT(DISTINCT c.zbid)`. Now remember how these tables are related; this should only be done for the rows in `c` which relate to an item in `b` which is owned by the respective shop, `a`.

I tried doing the following:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  COUNT(b.id) items,
  AVG(COALESCE(b.price,0)) average_price,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.zbid)
FROM shops a
LEFT JOIN shop_items b     ON b.cid=a.cid AND b.szbid=a.zbid
LEFT JOIN shop_inventory c ON c.cid=b.cid AND c.iid=b.id
WHERE a.cid=1
GROUP BY b.szbid,b.cid
```

However, this did not work as it messed up the `items` value. What is the proper way to achieve this result?

I also want to be able to return the total number of purchases made in each shop. This would be done by looking at `shop_inventory c` and adding up the `c.quantity` value for each shop. How would I add that in as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT    a.*,
          COALESCE(b.item_cnt,  0) AS item_cnt,
          COALESCE(b.avg_price, 0) AS avg_price,
          COALESCE(b.buyer_cnt, 0) AS buyer_cnt
FROM      shops a
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT    a.cid, 
                    a.szbid, 
                    COUNT(*)     AS item_cnt, 
                    AVG(a.price) AS avg_price,
                    b.buyer_cnt
          FROM      shop_items a
          LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT   cid,
                             iid,
                             COUNT(DISTINCT zbid) AS buyer_cnt
                    FROM     shop_inventory
                    WHERE    cid = 1
                    GROUP BY cid, 
                             iid
                    ) b ON a.cid = b.cid AND a.id = b.iid
          WHERE     a.cid = 1 AND
                    a.szbid <> 0
          GROUP BY  a.cid,
                    a.szbid
          ) b ON a.cid = b.cid AND a.zbid = b.szbid
WHERE     a.cid = 1 AND 
          a.zbid <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed query, spent the last 20 minutes trying to work out how it functions and I'm still slightly confused. In the innermost `LEFT JOIN`, you get the value `buyer_cnt`. Now this is a different value returned for each item. So why is it, in the outermost `LEFT JOIN`, that `b.buyer_cnt` works? Surely it should have to `SUM(b.buyer_cnt)`?

Comment: Actually, what I don't understand is how the innermost `JOIN` uses `a.id=b.iid`, when there are many `a.id`s returned by the outer query (except they have been grouped).

Comment: @KeirSimmons since `shop_items` seems to have a one-to-many relationship with `shop_inventory`, we have to first do an inner `GROUP BY` on `shop_inventory` (using `cid` and `iid`) so as to ensure that only one row joins for each `cid` -> `szbid` combination in the `shop_items` table. This way, we don't skew the aggregations by duplicating rows in the outer `GROUP BY` on `shop_items`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT c.zbid)` + `LEFT JOIN shop_inventory` you could write a subselect:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  COUNT(b.id) items,
  AVG(COALESCE(b.price,0)) average_price,

  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.zbid)
    FROM shop_inventory c
    WHERE c.cid=b.cid AND c.iid=b.id
  )

FROM shops a
LEFT JOIN shop_items b     ON b.cid=a.cid AND b.szbid=a.zbid
WHERE a.cid=1
GROUP BY b.szbid,b.cid
```